# Efficiently calculate creation rate during window in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

For each observation in my data, I'm trying to come up with the number of observations created in the previous 7 days.

```
obs       date
 A      1/1/2000
 B      1/4/2000
 C      1/5/2000
 D      1/10/2000
 E      1/20/2000
 F      1/1/2000
```

Would become:

```
obs       date       births last week
 A      1/1/2000            2
 B      1/4/2000            3
 C      1/5/2000            4
 D      1/10/2000           3
 E      1/20/2000           1
 F      1/1/2000            2
```

Right now I'm using the following method, but it's very slow:

```
def past_week(x,df):
    back = x['date'] - dt.timedelta(days=7)
    return df[(df['date'] >= back) & (df['date'] < x['date'])].count()

df['births_last_week'] = df.apply(lambda x: past_week(x,df),axis=1)
```

Edit: Having difficulty with duplicate dates. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. I've edited the example above to include a repeated date:

```
df['births last week'] = df.groupby('date').cumcount() + 1
pd.rolling_count(df.set_index('date'), 7 + 1, freq='D').loc[df.date] - 1
```

gives:

```
  date      births last week            
2000-01-01        1
2000-01-04        2
2000-01-05        3
2000-01-10        3
2000-01-20        1
2000-01-01        1
```

I've tried rolling_sum instead, but then all I get is NA values for births last week. I imagine there's something extremely obvious that I'm getting wrong, just not sure what.

Comment: Can there be duplicate dates?

Comment: Yes there can be duplicates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
df = pd.read_csv("birth.csv", delim_whitespace=True, parse_dates=["date"])
by_day = df.groupby("date").count().resample("D").fillna(0)
csum = by_day.cumsum()
last_week = csum - csum.shift(7).fillna(0)
final = last_week.loc[df.date]
```

producing

```
>>> final
            obs
date           
2000-01-01    2
2000-01-04    3
2000-01-05    4
2000-01-10    3
2000-01-20    1
2000-01-01    2
```

---

Step by step, first we get the DataFrame (you probably have this already):

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv("birth.csv", delim_whitespace=True, parse_dates=["date"])
>>> df
  obs       date
0   A 2000-01-01
1   B 2000-01-04
2   C 2000-01-05
3   D 2000-01-10
4   E 2000-01-20
5   F 2000-01-01
```

Then we groupby on date, and count the number of observations:

```
>>> df.groupby("date").count()
            obs
date           
2000-01-01    2
2000-01-04    1
2000-01-05    1
2000-01-10    1
2000-01-20    1
```

We can resample this to days; it'll be a much longer timeseries, of course, but memory is cheap and I'm lazy:

```
>>> df.groupby("date").count().resample("D")
            obs
date           
2000-01-01    2
2000-01-02  NaN
2000-01-03  NaN
2000-01-04    1
2000-01-05    1
2000-01-06  NaN
2000-01-07  NaN
2000-01-08  NaN
2000-01-09  NaN
2000-01-10    1
2000-01-11  NaN
2000-01-12  NaN
2000-01-13  NaN
2000-01-14  NaN
2000-01-15  NaN
2000-01-16  NaN
2000-01-17  NaN
2000-01-18  NaN
2000-01-19  NaN
2000-01-20    1
```

Get rid of the nans:

```
>>> by_day = df.groupby("date").count().resample("D").fillna(0)
>>> by_day
            obs
date           
2000-01-01    2
2000-01-02    0
2000-01-03    0
2000-01-04    1
2000-01-05    1
2000-01-06    0
2000-01-07    0
2000-01-08    0
2000-01-09    0
2000-01-10    1
2000-01-11    0
2000-01-12    0
2000-01-13    0
2000-01-14    0
2000-01-15    0
2000-01-16    0
2000-01-17    0
2000-01-18    0
2000-01-19    0
2000-01-20    1
```

And take the cumulative sum, as part of a manual rolling-sum process.  The default rolling sum has the wrong alignment, so I'll just subtract with a difference of one week:

```
>>> csum = by_day.cumsum()
>>> last_week = csum - csum.shift(7).fillna(0)
>>> last_week
            obs
date           
2000-01-01    2
2000-01-02    2
2000-01-03    2
2000-01-04    3
2000-01-05    4
2000-01-06    4
2000-01-07    4
2000-01-08    2
2000-01-09    2
2000-01-10    3
2000-01-11    2
2000-01-12    1
2000-01-13    1
2000-01-14    1
2000-01-15    1
2000-01-16    1
2000-01-17    0
2000-01-18    0
2000-01-19    0
2000-01-20    1
```

And then select the dates we care about:

```
>>> final = last_week.loc[df.date]
>>> final
            obs
date           
2000-01-01    2
2000-01-04    3
2000-01-05    4
2000-01-10    3
2000-01-20    1
2000-01-01    2
```

Comment: Any way to do this without resampling to days? Unfortunately the dataframes I'm working with are gigs in size already.

Comment: If there are constraints you're operating under, you should mention them in the question itself.  But even assuming you had a 200 year time window, wouldn't there only be about 200 * ~400 = 80000 days to record?

Comment: How do I merge the birth rate back to the original table? Indexes aren't compatible... Turns out size isn't such an issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [57]: df
Out[57]: 
  obs       date
0   A 2000-01-01
1   B 2000-01-04
2   C 2000-01-05
3   D 2000-01-10
4   E 2000-01-20

In [58]: df['births last week'] = 1

In [59]: pd.rolling_count(df.set_index('date'), 7 + 1, freq='D').loc[df.date] - 1
Out[59]: 
            births last week
2000-01-01                 0
2000-01-04                 1
2000-01-05                 2
2000-01-10                 2
2000-01-20                 0
```

I subtract 1 because `rolling_count` includes the current entry, and you don't.

Edit: To handle duplicate dates, as discussed in comments on your question, group by date and sum the 'births last week' column between inputs 58 and 59 above.

Comment: I don't think the `-1` is correct when you have duplicate dates

Comment: I actually have hours, minutes, and seconds in my dates, which is making this technique produce NAs. What's an easy way to set time to zero?

Comment: Also, how do you join this back to original dataframe?

Comment: How exactly does handling duplicate dates work? I've tried summing but it doesn't appear to be doing much.

Comment: Ah, Joris is right about the -1. I'm not sure what you mean by "doesn't appear to be doing much." Whip up a simple example with a duplicate in it and try some things -- all the ingredients are here.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I've added a new example above.

Comment: Anyone, anyone Bueller? Help?